# Using tf.py_func to generate input data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generator, pipeline, tensorflow-datasets

Python version = 3.6.3
Tensorflow version = 1.3.0

I have worked in `Keras` but am now trying to work directly in `TensorFlow`. **I am trying to implement the equivelent of `Keras`'s `fit_generator` whereby I don't have to have all training data loaded into memory at the start but can feed it into the network as needed for training.** The code below represents my attempt to start something like that, but if I am going about this all wrong I would love to know where in the docs I should look and what keywords I should use to search for this.

My system is currently based on a generator that reads through sqlite database files to extract `np.arrays` and then converts them into my desired data shape (a time series with one prediction for forward). I am trying to migrate that system now to work with Tensorflow `Dataset`s and getting stuck at applying `tf.py_func`. Here is how I am trying to work right now

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.contrib.data import Dataset, Iterator

import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

LOOKBACK_ROWS = 600 
DATA_DIR = '/mnt/derived_data/processedData'

files = os.listdir(DATA_DIR)

def data_from_files(f):
    with sqlite3.connect(DATA_DIR + f) as conn:
        results = conn.execute("SELECT col1, col2, FROM tbl")
        col_names = [d[0] for d in results.description]
        arr = np.array(results.fetchall())

    num_obs = arr.shape[0] - LOOKBACK_ROWS + 1

    X = np.zeros((num_obs, LOOKBACK_ROWS, 1), dtype = np.float32)
    Y = np.zeros((num_obs, 1), dtype = np.float32)

    for i in range(num_obs):
        idx = i + LOOKBACK_ROWS - 1
        X[i , :, 0] = arr[(idx - LOOKBACK_ROWS + 1):(idx + 1), 0]
        Y[i, 0] = arr[idx, 1]

    return tf.convert_to_tensor(X, name = 'X'), tf.convert_to_tensor(Y, name = 'Y')

filenames = tf.constant(files)

dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames))

dataset = dataset.map(lambda filename: tuple(tf.py_func(
    data_from_files,
    [filename],
    [tf.float32, tf.float32])))


iterator     = Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()
dataset_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(dataset_init_op)

    while True:
        try:
            elem = sess.run(next_element)
            print('Success')
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('End of dataset.')
            break
```

The initializations run fine, but then when I start the session and run I get the following errors:

```
  2017-10-16 16:58:45.227612: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
    2017-10-16 16:58:45.227615: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
    2017-10-16 16:58:45.227620: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0)
    2017-10-16 16:58:45.276138: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: TypeError: must be str, not bytes
    2017-10-16 16:58:45.276306: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Invalid argument: TypeError: must be str, not bytes
         [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0"](arg0)]]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
        return fn(*args)
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
        status, run_metadata)
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
        next(self.gen)
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
        pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: must be str, not bytes
         [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0"](arg0)]]
         [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, <unknown>], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Iterator)]]

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/usr/code/nn/data_folder/pipeline.py", line 51, in <module>
        elem = sess.run(next_element)
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
        run_metadata_ptr)
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
        feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
        options, run_metadata)
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
        raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: must be str, not bytes
         [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0"](arg0)]]
         [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, <unknown>], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Iterator)]]
    >>> python.el: native completion setup loaded
    >>>
```

Questions

(1) This seems like exactly a use case for `py_func` but am I wrong about that? If not, can anyone point me to some resources that show more in depth than the Tensorflow docs? (I did notice one potential related issue on git: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12396 but the fix of wrapping everything with a `tuple` did not help me).

(2) What is the general flow I should be following, particularly where I want to start with something like a bunch of filenames and output more than one training `Example` per file name?

Thank you.

Below I rewrote my script so that it can be a self-contained runnable example. I believe the issue is still the same as in the code above, but I am repasting the error as well to confirm.

Self contained runnable code example incorporating changes from @mrry's answer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np

LOOKBACK_ROWS = 600 

arr = np.random.random_sample((2000, 2))
np.save("npfile.npy", arr)

def data_from_files(f):

    arr = np.load(f)
    num_obs = arr.shape[0] - LOOKBACK_ROWS + 1

    X = np.zeros((num_obs, LOOKBACK_ROWS, 1), dtype = np.float32)
    Y = np.zeros((num_obs, 1), dtype = np.float32)

    for i in range(num_obs):
        idx = i + LOOKBACK_ROWS - 1
        X[i , :, 0] = arr[(idx - LOOKBACK_ROWS + 1):(idx + 1), 0]
        Y[i, 0] = arr[idx, 1]

    return X, Y

files = ["npfile.npy"]
filenames = tf.constant(files)


# NOTE: In TensorFlow 1.4, `tf.contrib.data` is now `tf.data`.
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

# NOTE: In TensorFlow 1.4, the `tuple` is no longer needed.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda filename: tuple(tf.py_func(
    data_from_files,
    [filename],
    [tf.float32, tf.float32])))

# NOTE: If you only have one `Dataset`, you do not need to use
# `Iterator.from_structure()`.
iterator     = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)

    while True:
        try:
            elem = sess.run(next_element)
            print('Success')
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('End of dataset.')
            break
```

Error:

```
2017-10-16 18:30:44.143668: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-10-16 18:30:44.143672: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-10-16 18:30:44.143679: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0)
2017-10-16 18:30:44.190852: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Unknown: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
2017-10-16 18:30:44.190959: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Unknown: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0"](arg0)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0"](arg0)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, <unknown>], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Iterator)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 48, in <module>
    elem = sess.run(next_element)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0"](arg0)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>, <unknown>], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Iterator)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking your questions in reverse order:

> What is the general flow I should be following, particularly where I want to start with something like a bunch of filenames and output more than one training Example per file name?

To transform one element into many, use the [`Dataset.flat_map(f)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) transformation. This transformation lets you define a function `f(x)` that **maps** a single element `x` to a nested `Dataset` object, and then it takes care of **flattening** the nested datasets.

> This seems like exactly a use case for `py_func` but am I wrong about that?

This is a use case for [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) but your program has a slight error: the `tf.py_func()` op expects that your function (`data_from_files()`) returns NumPy arrays, and **not** `tf.Tensor` objects. Simply returning `X` and `Y` should work.

---

With those two points answered, let's take a look at how you can rewrite your code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

LOOKBACK_ROWS = 600 
DATA_DIR = '/mnt/derived_data/processedData'

files = os.listdir(DATA_DIR)

def data_from_files(f):
    with sqlite3.connect(DATA_DIR + f) as conn:
        results = conn.execute("SELECT col1, col2, FROM tbl")
        col_names = [d[0] for d in results.description]
        arr = np.array(results.fetchall())

    num_obs = arr.shape[0] - LOOKBACK_ROWS + 1

    X = np.zeros((num_obs, LOOKBACK_ROWS, 1), dtype = np.float32)
    Y = np.zeros((num_obs, 1), dtype = np.float32)

    for i in range(num_obs):
        idx = i + LOOKBACK_ROWS - 1
        X[i , :, 0] = arr[(idx - LOOKBACK_ROWS + 1):(idx + 1), 0]
        Y[i, 0] = arr[idx, 1]

    return X, Y

filenames = tf.constant(files)

# NOTE: In TensorFlow 1.4, `tf.contrib.data` is now `tf.data`.
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

# NOTE: In TensorFlow 1.4, the `tuple` is no longer needed.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda filename: tuple(tf.py_func(
    data_from_files,
    [filename],
    [tf.float32, tf.float32])))

# NOTE: If you only have one `Dataset`, you do not need to use
# `Iterator.from_structure()`.
iterator     = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)

    while True:
        try:
            elem = sess.run(next_element)
            print('Success')
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('End of dataset.')
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed and helpful answer. I may be missing something, but I found that even incorporating your changes I still had the same error. I have appended standalone code in my example above as well as the error I get in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error (AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read') when i use tensorflow. I did these things: uninstall numpy, delete files about numpy in 'Lib\site-packages', reinstall numpy. And the error is gone. Maybe some mistakes Occurred where i updated numpy.